what differences are between slip of tongue and slip of brain?
what differences are between slip of tongue and slip of brain, according to p188-189 in Yule's Study of Languages?


I’m voting to close this question because it contains its own answer and is merely asking us to compare and contrast the quoted text.

Obviously, slips of the tongue (lapsus linguae) come from the brain. This distinction your text is trying to draw is really not anything standard.

"Slips of the brain" are mistakes in planning, "slips of the tongue" are mistakes in execution. The planning stage is earlier and more "central" to the brain, the execution involves some periphery. But of course, the brain is key in both cases.
